# Windows Phone use Background Agent to download files from Web

Tags: windows-phone

I want to develop a File Downloader in my Application. But I want to do this with a Background Agent, because I want to run the download when I deactivating the App or change the Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your download file is small, you can use the BackgroundTransferService. The limit of this service is 20mb when using cellular network, 100mb over wifi and unlimited only using wifi and external power.
If you need download big file without any limitation, you should using background thread to download and update proress to UI using event.